# Codeigniter Active Record (and not only that) peculiar problem on some server

Tags: php, mysql, oop, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm experiencing a strange problem while using CodeIgniter's Active Record class (**looks like not only that, check update at bottom of question**), and that happens only on some servers (belonging to the same provider). What happens is that the query is run only "partially", meaning that results are retrieved from mysql database, but any `where` or `join` or `select` clause is ignored.

A simple example:

```
$this->db->select('title,intro');
$this->db->from('content');
$this->db->where('published','1');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Doens't really work, because I get ALL fields and ALL results, even those with 'published' = '0'. The more complex the query, the worst the outcome.

Also, the same happens with any field datatype, so it's not a matter of using an INT and asking for a string. The above was just a sample, it happens with more "complex" queries like

```
$this->db->where('category','events');
$this->db->where('published','1');
$this->db->order_by('date','desc');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get('newsletter');
```

If I call `$this->db->last_query()` it returns FALSE (bool); The only way I have to make it work is use standard mysql syntax, and do like

```
$sql = "SELECT title,intro FROM content WHERE published = '1'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

This works without any problem. 
Since I've a fair amount of experience in CodeIgniter I don't think it's me who's making errors in using the AR, since those query works locally and on other servers without problem.

I searched the net for similar problems but seems I'm out of luck or good google-fu skills today. I don't even know what could be going wrong, as the log files doens't show any error, adn I don't know what to look for in php.ini maybe. Anyway, here some INI values that might be involved, but I'm clueless:

```
allow_call_time_pass_reference    Off   Off
allow_url_fopen                   On    On
always_populate_raw_post_data     Off   Off
auto_globals_jit                  On    On
browscap                          no value no value
define_syslog_variables           Off   Off
disable_classes                   no value no value
disable_functions                 no value no value
display_errors                    Off   Off
enable_dl                         On    On
error_reporting                   2047  2047
html_errors                       On    On
ignore_repeated_errors            Off   Off
ignore_repeated_source            Off   Off
ignore_user_abort                 Off   Off
implicit_flush                    Off   Off
log_errors                        On    On
magic_quotes_gpc                  On    On
magic_quotes_runtime              Off   Off
magic_quotes_sybase               Off   Off
register_argc_argv                Off   Off
register_globals                  On    On
register_long_arrays              On    On
safe_mode                         Off   Off
safe_mode_exec_dir                no value no value
safe_mode_gid                     Off   Off
safe_mode_include_dir             no value no value
```

Mysql:

```
Active Persistent Links 2
Active Links            2
Client API version  5.0.77
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.max_links         Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off
```

The virtual server runs PHP Version 5.1.6, on Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS).

What can I do to solve the problem? 
Do I have to change some value in php.INI? 
Or do I need to modify CI's ActiveRecord core?

## **Edit:**

In such environment, it seems that also loading resources (helpers, libraries, modules) doesn't work, unless they're autoloaded. And the native redirect() doesn't work! I think they're all releted but I might be opening another question for that, in case I found out I'm wrong. What could cause such behaviour?

Comment: published column having integer or varchar datatype ?

Comment: Published is an int column, but the same happens to varchars and whatever other type. There's no SQL error, simply the ActiveRecord "looses" the query parts, or at least that's what seems like

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing worth trying instead is:

```
$this->db->where('published', 1);
```

I recall Codeigniter to either incluse of exclude '' around 1 in the actual query depending on if the value is an integer, float or a string.

Do you use the latest version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: Yes, I use the latest one; also, $this->db->last_query() returns FALSE, which shouldn't in case the problem was just a where not maching! It looks like it's not retaining the query parts, and I don't know why. Anyway, I tried it and it's not working.