# codeigniter result_array is not working on real server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I'm working on codeigniter project with a database and it's working perfectly on the local host but when i uploaded it on real server alot of problems occurred.

I really made a lot of search but i couldn't find solution.

result_array() function is not working when i retrieve data from database and give me this error `" Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/mostafa/public_html/Sales/application/models/m_login.php on line 13 "`

this is my controller code

```
class c_login extends CI_Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function signin(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('m_login');
    $user = $this->m_login->signin($username, $password);

    if(!$user){
        echo "<script>alert('Your Username Or Password is Incorrect');</script>";
    }else{

        //set session
        $userData = array(
            'id' => $user[0]['id'],
            'name'  => $user[0]['name'],
            'admin' => $user[0]['admin']
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($userData);

        if ($user[0]['admin'] == 1) {
            redirect('c_home_admin');
        }else{
            redirect('c_home_user');
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this is the model code

```
class m_login extends CI_Model{
function insertUser($data) {
    $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}

public function signin($username, $password){
    $this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}}
```

and this is the database.php configurations :

```
$active_group = 'default';

$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';

$db['default']['username'] = 'root';

$db['default']['password'] = '**********';

$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';

$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had once a strange problem with AR similar to this, which I've never been able to pin down (even on SO). I solved writing the query manually and using `$this->db->query()` instead of building it with Active Record. Give it a try (for the record, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898043/codeigniter-active-record-and-not-only-that-peculiar-problem-on-some-server)

Comment: @DamienPirsy ... i tried to write the query manually and used var_dump() to fetch data .. but i got bool(false) as output !!!:((

Comment: I think the active record class is not working at all

Comment: are the php versions the same from local to server?

Comment: Can you put `$this->db->last_query()` under `$query = $this->db->get();` and try that query on the phpMyAdmin or some database tool manually and see if that pulls any info?

Comment: @KaiQing .. i doubt it is not the same but i don't know how to know the version of the server .. can you give me a link that may help ?

Comment: you can put `die(phpinfo());` at the top of index.php and it will show you.

Comment: @KaiQing ..   ok They are not the same !! 
my server works on php version 5.2.17 but my localhost works on php version 5.4.3

Comment: @ISuthanBala .. yes mate it pulled 
"string(74) "SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `username` = 'fofo' AND `password` = '999'"" ... the selection is done but it don't get any thing

Comment: Is there a reason not to update the server to latest php version? Or set your local to 5.2.17 just to see if you encounter the same issue? AR should work on any php 5+ but you never know. Could be you need to re-download the core or something.

Comment: @KaiQing ..how can i set my local to 5.2.17 ? .. i don't know what you mean by downloading the core !?

Comment: I do not think that this would be a PHP version issue. I would not downgrade my local, and if upgrading remote is not feasible, or possible, I'd not worry about it any further.

Comment: I agree it should not be a php version issue but since nothing else seems to be fixing this for him it might not be a bad idea to consider it an odd possibility. To quote Spock "If you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." - and by core I mean re-download the codeigniter core. Changing php versions may vary between software packages. Do you use wamp, xampp, mamp, etc?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the error we're looking at all in the first place. If the error was with that model itself, then the error should have been `Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object` NOT `Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/mostafa/public_html/Sales/application/models/m_login.php on line 13 ` because it wasn't the same when I tried it on a non-object. Can you please verify the line number of `return $query->result_array();` is indeed the 13?

Comment: it gives the same error when i use either ->result() or ->result_array()

Comment: I mean can you verify on your model if the line number of `$query->result_array();` is 13? sorry I should've been clear

Comment: yes it was 13 .. and i'm the one who should say sorry .. and thanks for help

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,60567 this is an old post about how to switch in wamp.

Comment: Try `var_dump($query)` above the `$query->result_array();` and post the response?

Comment: I did it guys .. i started uploading from start and made a new database ... i found that i didn't add the user to the database !! and i should set the host-name to 'local host' instead of '195.5 ....' :((( .. so sorry guys for this disturbance :) and great thanks for you all

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is whether your database schema is exactly the same on development as it is on live. If the tables are not the same (e.g. missing a field) you will get that error.

**EDIT**

Try rewrite your SQL query as follows:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM `users` where `username` = ? AND `password` = ?
";
$q = $this->db->query($sql, array($username, $password));
return $q->result_array();
```

(Sorry - posted it here in my answer, as the comment is looking wonky...)

Comment: What happens when you run the query in your admin tool such as PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: @Kabus Myburgh .. i copied and pasted the SQL code in the 2 databases with their different names but it is not working (if i understood what you mean)

Comment: nothing happens ... if i get data, it returns nothing
and if i inserted data  also

Comment: Please post your database schema with some sample data as it is on your live server?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?27zihts33a93qes ... this link for my database schema and i w'd like to insert a user for example

Comment: Don't worry - see edit of my answer. That would be a better next step.

Comment: when i print_r($returned variable) ... it returns Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in /home/mostafa/public_html/Sales/application/models/m_login.php on line 12